# How can I start a NPM app from a desktop shortcut?

Tags: bash, node.js, npm, desktop-shortcuts

I have created a desktop shortcut for a `npm` application called TMXEditor, but it doesn't work.

I can launch the app if I do `cd /home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor && npm start` on a terminal.

I put that in a bash file `/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh`. The application runs if I just run that script in a terminal. Its exact contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor && npm start
```

So I have created the .desktop file pointing to that:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TMXEditor
Exec=/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh
Icon=/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/icons/tmxeditor.png
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Translation;
Comment=
Path=/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor
```

The `.desktop` file is saved as `/home/souto/.local/share/applications/TMXEditor.desktop`.

I can see the shortcut in Rofi, but when I run it from there the application will not start.

I have also tried putting `Exec=xfce4-terminal -e "/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh`. In that case, I can see a terminal blinking for a fraction of a second but still the application will not run.

Both the .desktop and the bash files are executable:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 souto souto 296 feb 19 14:27 /home/souto/.local/share/applications/TMXEditor.desktop
-rwxrwxrwx 1 souto souto 67 feb 19 13:53 /home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh
```

My desktop environment is Xfce 4.18 (on arch linux) and I normally use zsh 5.9 as the shell.

I'd appreciate some help to debug this shorcut. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running it from the command line with `kioclient exec` it may provie useful diagnosis information?

Comment: Welcome, try changing the `Exec` to `Exec=/bin/bash /home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh`.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity no difference. the start.sh script starts with `#!/bin/bash` in any case.

Comment: @Delfin I don't know this `kioclient` utility and either package nor yay seems to have a relevant package for it. Do you know what is the name of the package?

Comment: In my system it is shipped by kde-cli-tools5

Comment: thanks @Delfin I could install it. However, the [output](https://imgur.com/CvWnVlr.png) I get in the terminal when I run `kioclient exec /home/souto/.local/share/applications/TMXEditor.desktop` is identical to what I get when I run `/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh`.

Comment: What is the contents of the script?

Comment: @Delfin I have now updated my original post to include that info, I thought it was clear. The file has two lines. The first one says `#!/bin/bash` and the second one says `cd /home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor && npm start`.

Comment: have you tried to launch the application from the command line without the desktop file?

Comment: Have you tried to use the full path of `npm`?, because .bashrc is never sourced when running desktop files

Comment: @Delfin yes, I have tried to launch the application from the command line without the desktop file. That's the two first things I mention in my original post: "I can launch the app if I do `cd /home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor && npm start` on a terminal. I put that in a bash file `/home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor/start.sh`. The application runs if I just run that script in a terminal."

Comment: Following your last tip @Delfin, I have now tried putting `cd /home/souto/Apps/maxprograms/TMXEditor && /home/souto/.reflex/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin/npm start` (with shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the first line), but to no avail.

Comment: I think you probably have a Enviroment variable that is being set at `~/.bashrc` thus why the app cannot be launched from the desktop file.

Comment: You should run `env > ~/desktop_env` in the script and compare it aganist `env` in your terminal

Comment: Putting a shebang will do noting `~/.bachrc` is only executed in interactive sessions of bash

Comment: Bingo! It works if I add `PATH=/home/souto/.reflex/.bun/bin:/home/souto/.reflex/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin:/home/souto/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/souto/.local/bin` to the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that running it with the utility `kioclient exec` is almost in guaranty that the problem is some missing additions to the environment variables which can be checked comparing `env` in the terminal against `env` in the script that the Desktop file is referencing.

Note that adding a shebang in bash will do nothing about modifications to the environment at `~/.bashrc` because it is only executed in interactive bash sessions, as the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) steht.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the problem was that the .desktop file cannot read enviroment variables set at ~/.bashrc.